# use same file selected in bash process

Tags: bash

In the below portion of a `bash` script the user selects  a file from a directory.

```
select file in $(cd /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-14-2016/bedtools;ls);do break;done
```

**files in directory**

```
123_base_counts.txt
456_base_counts.txt
789_base_counts.txt
```

**second portion of `bash` currently** (user manually selects the file)

```
select file in $(cd /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-14-2016/bedtools;ls);do break;done
```

What I am trying to do is if the user selects `123_base_counts.txt` in the first `select`, then in the second select whatever the name of the file, the one that starts with `123` is used.

The directory in the second `select` has files names:

```
123_variant_strandbias_readcount.vcf.hg19_multianno_removed_final (this one is automatically selected because it has the same starting digits as the original file)
456_variant_strandbias_readcount.vcf.hg19_multianno_removed_final
789_variant_strandbias_readcount.vcf.hg19_multianno_removed_final
```

I can manually `select` each file but I am not sure how to automate the selection.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will the filenames always have an underscore after the numeric portion?
If so you could do the following

```
nameNumeric=$(echo $file | awk -F'_' '{print $1}');
secondFile=$(ls /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-14-2016/bedtools/${nameNumeric}*);
```

Comment: Yees there will always be an `_` after the numeric portion.  Thank you :).